# Why we can't use single quote in c#?

Tags: c#, single-quotes

I'm a newbie in c# , recently came to know that i can't use single quote to define a string.
But Why?

example :

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
```

This one works but

```
Console.WriteLine('hello world');
```

this one not!

Comment: Single quotes are for [`char` literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char#literals), that's why.

Comment: Single qoutes are used to define a **'c'haracter** (Single letter) and double quotes are used to define a **"string"**.